# Why is this grammatically correct? - "I would like to cancel the job that I had ordered"

Tags: tense, past-perfect, past-simple, past-vs-past-perfect

As the title states, would you mind teaching me why this sentence is grammatically correct?

> "I would like to cancel the job that I had ordered"

The reason I ask is that the below sentence doesn't sound wrong to me, without the "had":

> "I would like to cancel the job that I ordered"

Lastly, does the below sentence have the same meaning as the first example? If so, what is the grammatical difference?

> "I want to cancel that job I ordered"

Answer (score 1):

I think the sentence is fine without the "had", because it is clear the ordering happened in the past. I don't know why it is used in this sentence. If the cancelling happened in the past as well it would be correct: "I wanted to cancel the job that I had ordered". Here the "had" makes it clear the ordering happened before the cancelling in the past.